# whether to set variable as ID or as nominal for multiple imputation

Tags: r, multiple-imputation

Using Amelia II for multiple imputation in R, I cannot find elaborate explanations of whether to set variables to being ID or nominal (perhaps a [Stata forum post](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1697487-multiple-imputation-for-index-variable) comes closest). How to choose?

In my case I have concatenated, or appended, some data drawn from the same world and made an ID variable representing (a) each set. Note each set contains a time-series, 1-1000. The data also includes a variable representing (b) the observations/units-of-analysis, let's call them sailors; their names being unique across the concatenated data. Another column describes that sailors (c) belong to groups, or ships, but there are missing values such that not all shipmembers and ships are identified (heck, sometimes more ships  have been determined than there really are). Most columns reflect data at the level of ships which then should take the same values for all sailors.

I suppose these three variables a-c are important for filling out the gaps in e.g. variable c. But they strike me as being ID variables, which are not 'considered for analysis'. This is somewhat confusing.

Thanks a lot.